# Adding a value + value labels to all variables in an SPSS dataset

Tags: spss

I'd like to add a value and a label to every variable in my dataset. It's my understanding that the VALUE LABELS command erases values+labels already in the variables (and not included in the command), so I'd like not to do that.

Any ideas? Thank you!

Comment: do you have a table of variables with their labels and value labels? if you do, that can be automatically turned into syntax that creates those labels

Comment: I have an excel sheet with the variables and their labels--is that what you mean? I appreciate the response.

Answer (score 1):

Once you've prepared a table for variable labels and a table for value labels, you can use them to create a syntax that will put them in the dataset.

read the following text to get an example of how your variable label list should look like:

```
data list list/vr (a10) lb (a50).
begin data
"myvar1" "this is the label for var1"
"myvar2" "this is the label for var2"
"myvar3" "this is the label for var3"
end data.
```

Now you can run the following syntax:

```
string cmd1 (a100).
compute cmd1=concat("variable labels ", rtrim(vr), "  '", rtrim(lb), "'.").
write out = "yourpath\do variable labels.sps" /cmd1.
exe.
```

This will create a new syntax called `do variable labels.sps` which contains the `variable labels` commands.
Now for value labels - start with the following example of how your table should look:

```
data list list/vr (a10) vl (f3) lb (a50).
begin data
"myvar1" 1 "cat"
"myvar1" 2 "dog"
"myvar1" 3 "horse"
"myvar2" 1 "bed"
"myvar2" 2 "table"
"myvar2" 3 "chair"
end data.
```

Once the table is prepared, use the following syntax:

```
string cmd2 (a100).
compute cmd2=concat("add value labels  ", rtrim(vr), "  ", string(vl,f3), "  '", rtrim(lb), "'.").
write out = "yourpath\do value labels.sps" /cmd2.
exe.
```

Now you can use the new syntax created called `do value labels.sps`.

You can also look into `insert` command to run the two new syntaxes from your main syntax without opening them.

Answer (score 1):

If you'd like to label your variables (for ex: v1 v2 v3) you can use:

```
VARIABLE LABELS
 v1 'label for v1'
 v2 'label for v2'
 v3 'label for v3' .
```

If you'd like to add labels to the values associated with your variables, but NOT lose any existing value labels you can use:

```
ADD VALUE LABELS
 v1
  1 'label for v1=1'
  2 'label for v1=2' /
v2
 1 'label for v2=1'
 2 'label for v2=2' /
v3
 1 'label for v3=1'
 2 'label for v3=2' .
```

If there were any previously existing labels, they will still persist (unless explicitly overwritten in your ADD VALUES command).

Answer (score 0):

As user @user45392 pointed out you can use the `ADD VALUE LABELS` command.

In order to add the same value und label to every variable in your data set you can simply write the keyword `ALL` at the place of your variable list.

```
ADD VALUE LABELS ALL
   N "new label".
```

- `N` stands for the new added value.
- Values are added only for numeric variables.